# Case specific bootstrap-datepicker configuration

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Using:

```
<link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="./bootstrap/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="./css/customize.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Requirements:
 1. Having 'From' and 'To' calendars
 2. Both 'From' and 'To' should have disabled dates greater than 'current date'
 3. Date in 'To' should be <= date in 'From'
 4. If 'From' date is being selected and it is > then 'To' date. Then 'To' date should be updated to 'From' == 'To'
 5. 'From' date is selected. When 'To' date is being selected then dates inside the 'To' calendar that are < 'From' date should be disabled.
 6. Auto-advancement from 'From' to 'To'

I have got this far:

```
    $(function(){
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);


    var from = $('#fromDate').datepicker({
      onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() > now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
      }
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
      if (ev.date.valueOf() > to.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        to.setValue(newDate);
      }
      from.hide();
      $('#toDate')[0].focus();
    }).data('datepicker');
    var to = $('#toDate').datepicker({
      onRender: function(date) {
        return ((date.valueOf() <= from.date.valueOf()) || (date.valueOf() > now.valueOf()) ? 'disabled' : '');
      }
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
      to.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
    });
```

Issues:
1. When I first select from 'To' dates calendar I have only the 'current date' available.
2. No auto-advancement.
3. When selected 'From' date and then 'To' date calendar shows only 'current date'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps:

With https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

```
$(function(){

    var dateStart = $('#date-start')
    .datepicker({
        startDate: new Date()
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(ev){
        dateEnd.datepicker('setStartDate', ev.date);
        dateStart.datepicker('hide');
        dateEnd.focus();
    });

    var dateEnd = $('#date-end')
    .datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(ev){
        dateStart.datepicker('setEndDate', ev.date);
        dateEnd.datepicker('hide');
    });
});
```